# How can I connect my Unity3D application to a MySQL database on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, database, unity-game-engine, database-connection, monodevelop

I've been reading a ton about the best way to get my Unity application to be able to retrieve data from a MySQL database. The consensus is that for security purposes, the database connection should be set up in PHP and then the Unity code should interact with the PHP.

So instead of:

Unity -> MySQL

We have:

Unity -> PHP -> MySQL.

That's great and everything, but I'm not really worried about security for my app. I'm working on a project for my final year at university; it's something that could be considered internal software and so the user of the application will also own the database. Therefore I have no concerns over security.

So all I want is to get this Unity -> MySQL connection working. I feel like I'm so close but have gotten stuck with some errors and don't know where to go from here.

**My Database Connection Code**

```
public class TweetDAO {

    private string connString;

    public TweetDAO()
    {
        connString = "Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=tweets; Uid=root; Pwd=root;";
    }

    public string ReadString(string query)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection (connString);
        string result = "";

        try {

            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand ();
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            command.CommandText = query;
            conn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader ();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }

        } 
        catch (MySqlException ex) {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            conn.Dispose ();
            conn = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

When I run this I get `SocketException: Connection refused` and the exception message is `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

I thought that this must just be something wrong with my connection string but I've tried so many different combinations and nothing seems to work.

I would be very grateful for any help with this.

Thank you! :)

Comment: What happens when you request http://127.0.0.1/3306 in your browser?

Comment: @OscarLundberg Aha.. Um well when I go to 127.0.0.1:3306 I get Can't connect to the server. :\ I'm using MAMP on Mac OSX for my server running MySQL. When I look at phpMyAdmin I'm connecting to http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/?lang=en#PMAURL-0:index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=f87f04abd37b68623fda35adc7077365

Comment: So did you try changing the port to 8888?

Comment: Ahh that seems to have worked. I knew it would be something small like that! Thank you. You can put that as an answer if you like and I'll accept it. I'm having an error `Reading from the stream has failed.` now but I think that's a problem with my database table and the query I'm running. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we concluded in the comments, the problem is that the port defined in the connection string differs from the port setup in your server client. (XAMPP, WAMP etc.)

The easiest way to quickly test problems like this is in my opinion to manually check it through the browser. While it won't solve anything, depending on what is shown in your browser you should be able to figure out what or where something went wrong.

Comment: Yes thank you for this tip. What confused me is that MAMP says "Use port 3306 for MySQL" but then in the MAMP settings it was actually using port 8889. Now I understand that I need to make sure both the server and the connection string are in agreement :)